# (void-function closure) with Magit

Tags: magit

I have Magit installed and it used to work fine. However of late, I am running into the following error when I run `magit-status`.

```
Turning on magit-auto-revert-mode...done
run-hooks: Symbol’s function definition is void: closure
```

I have tried deleting `elpa` and reinstalling packages from scratch, new versions of Magit has also been released in the meantime, but none of those helped solve the problem. This is what I get with `(setq debug-on-error t)`

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function closure)
  closure()
  run-hooks(magit-post-display-buffer-hook)
  magit-display-buffer(#<buffer magit: dotemacs>)
  magit-setup-buffer-internal(magit-status-mode nil ((magit-buffer-diff-args ("--no-ext-diff")) (magit-buffer-diff-files nil) (magit-buffer-log-args ("-n256" "--decorate")) (magit-buffer-log-files nil)))
  magit-status-setup-buffer("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/")
  magit-status(nil ((7 . 4) (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" . config) . #<hash-table equal 19/65 0x1558fd48cbb1>) (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" . magit-toplevel) . "/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/") (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" "rev-parse" "--show-cdup") . "") (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel") . "/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs")))
  funcall-interactively(magit-status nil ((7 . 4) (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" . config) . #<hash-table equal 19/65 0x1558fd48cbb1>) (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" . magit-toplevel) . "/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/") (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" "rev-parse" "--show-cdup") . "") (("/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs/" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel") . "/home/swarnendu/github/dotemacs")))
  call-interactively(magit-status nil nil)
  command-execute(magit-status)
```

I am using GNU Emacs 28.0.50 on Ubuntu 18.04. I get the same error with Emacs 26.3. Please let me know how can I resolve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function closure)
>   closure()
>   run-hooks(magit-post-display-buffer-hook)
> ```

You should see that as a hint as to what to do next:

1. Inspect the value of `magit-post-display-buffer-hook` (using `M-x describe-variable`).
2. Grep you `~/.emacs.d` for `magit-post-display-buffer-hook` (using `M-x rgrep`).

Inspect the things that you find. Maybe comment some of them to narrow things down.

It's probably not an issue in Magit or we would have heard about it already. It could of course be a very recent regression but is more likely its an issue in some third-party package or even more likely your configuration.

Magit [provides some tooling](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Debugging-Tools.html) to help you figure out whether the issue is in Magit or your own configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My configuration had the following to open Magit buffer in a full frame.
```
(magit-post-display-buffer-hook #'(lambda ()
                                       (when (derived-mode-p 'magit-status-mode)
                                         (delete-other-windows))))
```
Disabling it allows Magit to work.

Comment: You shouldn't #'quote lambda forms. Maybe that's all there is to it.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use `'(lambda...)`, but `function`-quoting with `#'(lambda...)` *should* (I believe) be entirely equivalent to unquoted (but self-quoting) `(lambda...)`.

Comment: If the user is switching between (unstable) Emacs 28.0.50 and 26.3, I am curious as to whether the relevant files were byte-compiled by the same version in which they were loaded.

Comment: I would advise to never add lambda forms to hook variables *at all*, though.  Always use named functions (i.e. symbols) in hooks -- it eliminates a number of problems and potential problems.